# duplicating values in a column based on criteria in python

Tags: python, filter, duplicates

Assume we have a dataframe df(2000, 20) I wish to change values from the first column on a specific criteria. For the following example I will just demonstrate the 2 columns we are interested in

```
df1
A                                             B
A-0012-Alex                                A-0012-whatever
A-0012-Alex                                A-0085-George 
A-0085-John                                A-0085-Nick
A-ABCD-Ivan                                A-ABCD-Julia
```

Here the issue is with the second row. The criteria is the following

- Check if value in column B has the same 4 digits(could be a number could be letters) as column A. For example in the first row we check if column A has the 0012, in second row if it has 0085, in the fourth ABCD etc
- If yes we are ok
- If not we should change column A according to those specific 4 digits but duplicate the correct value from column A!
  In our example the correct result is the following

```
df1
A                                             B
A-0012-Alex                                A-0012-whatever
A-0085-John                                A-0085-George 
A-0085-John                                A-0085-Nick
A-ABCD-Ivan                                A-ABCD-Julia
```

We saw that in column B the 4 digits are 0085 and the corresponding 4 digits in column A match with A-0085-John. I should mention that I have created a dataframe df(50,1) with all the unique values of A column so when I compare the 4 digits from column B and column A I can fetch the correct value from df2. However, I am not sure about the following

- How to fetch the correct value that I need from df2 and replace it to the column A

Edit: I have created a column with True or False whether the 4 digits in column A and column B are the same by using the command .str.slice() and then checking if they are equal
So my dataframe that needs to be changed is the following

```
df1
A                                             B                     c
A-0012-Alex                                A-0012-whatever         True
A-0012-Alex                                A-0085-George           False
A-0085-John                                A-0085-Nick             True
A-ABCD-Ivan                                A-ABCD-Julia            True
```

and my dataframe with the unique values is the following

```
df2          
0                                    4 digits
A-0012-Alex                          0012
A-0085-John                          0085
A-ABCD-Ivan                          ABCD
etc
```

How can I check when column c is False and change column A based on df2?

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following:

```py
cols = df1.columns
df1 = df1.assign(digits_A=df1["A"].str[2:6], digits_B=df1["B"].str[2:6])
df1 = df1.merge(
    df1[["A", "digits_A"]].drop_duplicates(),
    left_on="digits_B", right_on="digits_A",
    how="left",
    suffixes=("_old", "")
)[cols]
```

Result for the following `df1`

```
             A                B  C  D
0  A-0012-Alex  A-0012-whatever  1  a
1  A-0012-Alex    A-0085-George  2  b
2  A-0085-John      A-0085-Nick  3  c
3  A-ABCD-Ivan     A-ABCD-Julia  4  d
```

is

```
             A                B  C  D
0  A-0012-Alex  A-0012-whatever  1  a
1  A-0085-John    A-0085-George  2  b
2  A-0085-John      A-0085-Nick  3  c
3  A-ABCD-Ivan     A-ABCD-Julia  4  d
```

Comment: Hey Timus. Thank you for the feedback! Just one question though: in my original dataframe there are 21 columns. Since I want to keep the rest of the columns should at the end instead of [["A", "B"]] write all the other columns by name? Or there is an automatic way to do it so I do not have to hardcode 21 columns?

Comment: @Alex See my edit.